# Why Don't Variables Reset in a Closure (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, self-invoking-function

I've been trying to learn about closures, but one thing still perplexes me. If I have the following code:

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

add();
add();
add();

// Returns "3"
```

If I call add() three times, why dosen't it set counter to zero every time, then return the anonymous funtion that increments counter by one? Does it skip over it once the self-invoking function runs? Sorry if the question seems simple, I'm having a hard time understanding it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `add` is not the outside function, declaring `counter`; it's the **inside** function, **referring** to `counter`. Look real close.

Comment: just `console.log(String(add))` and you'll see. There's no `counter = 0` in that function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I call add() three times, why dosen't it set counter to zero every time, then return the anonymous funtion that increments counter by one?

Because `add` **is** that anonymous function, because the function containing `counter` got **called** and its result was assigned to `add`:

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();
//^^----------- calls the outer function, returns the anonymous inner function
```

If you *didn't* call it:

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
});
//^--- no () here
```

...then `add` would do what you said, it would return a new function with its own counter, each time you called it:

```js
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
});

var a = add();
var b = add();
var c = add();

console.log("a's first call:  " + a());
console.log("a's second call: " + a());
console.log("a's third call:  " + a());
console.log("b's first call:  " + b());
console.log("b's second call: " + b());
console.log("b's third call:  " + b());

console.log("a's fourth call: " + a());
console.log("b's fourth call: " + b());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That's not *resetting* `counter`, that's creating a new counter each time.

Answer (score 2):

By calling `add()` you are not actually executing outer function but instead you are executing inner function. For inner function, counter is like a global variable that has been set once to `0` and then it was never set again to `0`. On calling `add()` you are executing lines inside inner function thus incrementing counter.

Answer (score 2):

The value assigned to `add` is the result of the IIFE, in which the closure was created. Maybe it's more obvious what will happen when `add()` is called, when its creating is written as follows (equivalent to your original code):

```
var add;
(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    add = function () {return counter += 1;};
})();
```

Comment: So what my code does is run the outer function _once_, which sets the variable counter to zero, and then sets add to a function that increments counter? So it would be technically referring the variable counter from another function, the one that is self invoking?

Comment: @Mister_Maybe Yes, exactly that. And "referring to the variable from another scope" is exactly what [closures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) are about

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thank you!